# What US laws currently impede the fight against COVID-19?

Tags: united-states

There must be current US laws that forbid actions which, if taken, would help slow or stop the spread of COVID-19. What are they?

EDIT: in response to comments asking what evidence there is that such laws exist, I would note the current case counts and test counts in a few countries, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic&oldid=945135567):

```
Country         Cases       Tests      Ratio
  India            62       4058        65
  South Korea    7755    222,395        29
  Philippines      49        663        13
  USA            1275       8554         6.7
```

When it comes to testing, we suck. And then there are reports of people who wanted a test but couldn't get one in [New York](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/11/nyregion/coronavirus-testing-newyork.html.) and [Washington State](https://www.washingtonpost.com/health/coronavirus-may-have-spread-undetected-for-weeks-in-washington-state/2020/03/01/0f292336-5bcc-11ea-9055-5fa12981bbbf_story.html). Contrast the situation in [South Korea](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-51836898). Faced with a novel and obviously problematic situation, they adapted in a tremendous hurry, with innovative solutions in use within days.

FURTHER EDIT: Mike Pence appears to [agree](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/coronavirus-us-testing-red-tape-mike-pence-vice-president/) that regulations and/or laws are getting in the way of testing.

Comment: The title and the body ask things that are completely opposite.

Comment: Why do you assume that there *must* be such laws? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

> What US laws currently impede the fight against COVID-19?

It is not that such laws *impede* (that is, *ex-ante*) the fight against coronavirus. Instead, prosecution for not abiding by those laws *under circumstances of emergency* would lead to the absurd outcome of penalizing (*ex-post*) people's efforts toward stopping the spread of the virus. Thus, it is a matter of balancing the *competing interests* of constitutional/statutory freedoms on the one side, and public policy or the common good on the other side.

As an example, consider the US government's likely decision to restrict or prohibit *interstate travel*. This prohibition seems justifiable as an attempt to curb the spread of the virus.

An infected person could complain in terms of [*U.S. v. Guest*, 383 US 745, 758 (1966)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19661128383us74511071) ("*freedom to travel throughout the United States has long been recognized as a basic right under the Constitution*", citing cases). However, leaving that person's *freedom of movement* unaltered exposes the population of the destination [virus-free] state(s) to a high risk of contagion, which is precisely what the government intended to prevent.

Most examples have to do with the *freedom of movement*. In addition to that, any form of quarantine or a prohibition to attend gatherings might also be construed as a hindrance to people's *freedom of expression* or their *right to assemble* as premised on the [First Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/first_amendment). The rationale is inline with [the argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_association#United_States_Constitution) that "*people can engage in effective speech only when they join others*". But, similar to the previous example, the risk and impact of contagion are too high to preserve or remedy the person's said rights under a situation that can easily get --or might already be getting-- out of control.

Note: This is not intended to be an exhaustive answer.